# Snowflake custom OAuth client fails with invalid_client error?

Tags: oauth, passport.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a custom OAuth client for the snowflake account by referring documentation here, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html

I created an OAuth custom instance for my local using the following query:

```
create security integration My_Snowflake_Connector
  type = oauth
  enabled = true
  oauth_client = custom
  oauth_client_type = 'CONFIDENTIAL'
  oauth_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:4200/api/auth/callback/snowflake'
  oauth_issue_refresh_tokens = true
  oauth_refresh_token_validity = 86400
  blocked_roles_list = ()
  pre_authorized_roles_list = ('SYSADMIN', 'ACCOUNTADMIN', 'SECURITYADMIN')
  oauth_allow_non_tls_redirect_uri = true
```

I have obtained authorization & token URLs using the following query:

```
DESCRIBE security integration My_Snowflake_Connector
```

I also obtained secrets using the following query:

```
SELECT SYSTEM$SHOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRETS( 'MY_SNOWFLAKE_CONNEECTOR' )
```

I have used `passport-oauth2` plugin & `OAuth2Strategy`

On initiating OAuth flow I am rightly taken to the snowflake account I log in it shows the OAuth consent screen but upon redirection, I get an error `invalid_client`.

I am getting the following error JSON blob:

```
{\n  "data" : null,\n  "error" : "invalid_client",\n  "code" : null,\n  "message" : "This is an invalid client.",\n  "success" : false,\n  "headers" : null\n}
```

I have verified the callback URL, client id & secret none seems to be wrong.

What may be wrong with my configuration?

***Update***

We could not figure out the reason behind the OAuth error, Finally, we ended up using the Node js client from snowflake. For more info: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver.html

Comment: SELECT SYSTEM$SHOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRETS( 'MU_SNOWFLAKE_CONNEECTOR' ) is different from the integration object "My_Snowflake_Connector". Or was it just a typo while drafting this question?

Comment: @SrinathMenon yeah typo, Corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

I could see a similar error when testing OAuth2 from Postman when Client Authentication is set to "Send Client Credentials in body".

On changing this to "Send as Basic Auth Header",token generation works fine and proceeds successfully.

I guess this change should resolve the issue in your case as well. One of the  reference that I checked is here : https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/pull/316